# Animation defined in XML doesn't start

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

I found the pngs for the standard progress spinner in Android. However, when I try to animate them in a similar way to how android does it with the following code nothing happens. They just appear to be a static icons.

The button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@anim/anim"
    android:drawableRight="@anim/anim" >
</Button>
```

The animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_outer_holo" 
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is it even possible to start animations automatically that is defined in XML only or do they have to be started with java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `animated-rotate` but that will only work on API 11+. If you use `rotate`, then you'll have to start them in Java, and animate them by animating the level (`drawable.setLevel()`) between `0` and `10000` (sounds weird? It is, but it's how it's done).